# php mathematical addition of numerical values in 2 associative arrays

Tags: php, associative-array, addition

Probably a simple one for you :

I have 2 arrays

```
$array1 = array(
  'foo' => 5,
  'bar' => 10,
  'baz' => 6
);

$array2 = array(
  'x' => 100,
  'y' => 200,
  'baz' => 30
);
```

I wish to get a third array by combining both the above, which should be :

```
$result_array = array(
  'foo' => 5,
  'bar' => 10,
  'baz' => 36,
  'x' => 100,
  'y' => 200,
);
```

Is there any built in 'array - way' to do this, or will I have to write my own function ?
Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
$resultArray = $array1;
foreach($array2 as $key => $value) {
   if (isset($resultArray[$key])) {
      $resultArray[$key] += $value;
   } else {
      $resultArray[$key] = $value;
   }
}
```

Comment: thanks, that works. How come there's no built in way for this i wonder. by the way, I havent negative voted any of the answers on this page ! i cant - vote anyways ;p

Comment: Probably because you want to add the matching values, others might want to subtract, others to do a logical and, etc... so you'd need a function for every possible operation. And it isn't exactly difficult to write your own, just a few short lines of code

Answer (score 1):

There's no built-in function for this, you'll have to write your own.

Comment: Not sure why this got downvoted; it explicitly and specifically answered the question: "Is there a function, or do I have to make my own?"

Answer (score -2):

you need

```
$newArray = $array1;
foreach($array2 as $key => $value) {
    if(array_key_exists($key, $newArray)){
     $newArray[$key] += $value;
    }else{
     $newArray[$key] = $value;
    }
}
```

Comment: OP is requesting that the values be added when the keys match

Comment: sorry, that ate up 6 from baz